# как сделать предупреждение что юзер не ввел знак

Tags: python-3.7

как сделать предупреждение что юзер не ввел знак

```
ask = str(input("sign arithmetic "))
p = "+"
m = "-"
mult = "*"
div = "/"
x = int(input("enter first integer num "))
y = int(input("enter second integer num "))

try:
    if ask == p:
        res = x + y
        print(res)
    if ask == m:
        res = x - y
        print(res)
    if ask == div:
        try:
            res = x / y
            print(res)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Error. Division by zero. :(")
    if ask == mult:
        res = x * y
        print(res)
    input("Press ENTER to exit :)")
except:
    print("error")
```

Comment: `if ask not in p and ask not in m and ask not in mult and ask not in div:
    raise("Unknown sign")`

Answer (score 0):

Положим запрос знака в цикл и будем выполнять цикл, пока не будет введён правильный знак:

```
p = "+"
m = "-"
mult = "*"
div = "/"
while True:
    ask = str(input("sign arithmetic "))
    if ask == p or ask == m or ask == mult or ask == div:
        break
    print("wrong operator. Please repeat.")
```